# Is it possible to filter based off of a value within a composite type in Diesel?

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

The following code represents what I'm trying to do. This `INVENTORY_ID` composite type (an item type and an instance number) is used as a group nearly everywhere else, but I have one use-case where I need to filter based on only part of it (the item type). Is this possible in diesel without just loading the entire table and filtering using normal iterators?

SQL table and type definition

```sql
CREATE TYPE INVENTORY_ID AS (item_type INTEGER, item_instance INTEGER)
CREATE TABLE inventory (
  item_id INVENTORY_ID PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
  ...
)
```

Rust code using diesel:

```rust
#[derive(FromSqlRow, AsExpression, PartialEq, ToSql, FromSql)]
#[diesel(sql_type = schema::sql_types::InventoryId)]
pub struct InventoryId {
  item_type: i32,
  item_instance: i32
}
pub struct Item {
  item_id: InventoryId,
  ...
}

fn get_all_of_type(id: i32, conn: &mut PgConnection) -> Vec<InventoryId> {
  use schema::inventory;
  inventory::table
    .filter(inventory::item_id.item_type.eq(id)) // can't find how to do this part
    .select(inventory::item_id)
    .load(conn)
    .unwrap()
}
```

I've also tried:

```
.filter(inventory::item_id.as_sql().0.eq(id))
.filter(inventory::item_id.0.eq(id))
.filter(inventory::item_id.as_sql().item_type.eq(id))
```

but none have worked so far.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would have to construct the SQL filter manually:

```rust
.filter(diesel::dsl::sql("(inventory.item_id).item_type = ").bind::<Integer, _>(id))
```

See [composite access syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html#ROWTYPES-ACCESSING) and [`diesel::dsl::sql`](https://docs.rs/diesel/latest/diesel/dsl/fn.sql.html).